# How do you prevent a computer from making changes on sourcetree?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Im working with unity, and I have a main computer pushing changes that are then pulled by a secondary computer, to keep the projects synced.  The secondary computer is not supposed to make any changes, only receive them.

The only problem is that whenever i go to pull on my second pc, it wants me to stash about 73,000 changes, which takes about 5 minutes to do.

How can i prevent sourcetree from detecting these changes so i dont have to stash them,
or is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you checking in files that are build products?  If so, that's likely your problem.

Comment: Make sure you are using a proper .gitignore file for Unity projects. Here's an example: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore  If you have not excluded the Library directory in particular you'll have nothing but trouble. `git reset --hard && git clean -fxd` will remove any changes in the local repo and then pulling should be fine.

Comment: I am using the reccomended unity .gitignore, but that doesnt seem to work, even though i have it in both the repository directory and the unity project directory.  Yet github desktop still tries to include changes to library and temp in the commit.

Comment: @LeonHogan https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/7976758

Comment: "both the repository directory and the project directory" suggests your folder structure is incompatible with the unity ```.gitignore```.  That gitignore expects the repo TLD to be the project folder. (eg, "Project Name/.git" folder sibling to "Project Name/Assets" folder)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.  I had the recommended unity .gitignore file, however it was placed one folder too high.  The .gitignore file MUST be located alongside the Asset and Library folders for it to work.